# I am working with spring 4 and hibernate 4, I have showed my configuration file and libs , but getting UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Which jar file is missing:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'myHomeController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'scm_service'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'scmServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'scmdao'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'scmDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   javax/transaction/SystemException : Unsupported major.minor version
>   51.0 (unable to load class javax.transaction.SystemException)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:171)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5266)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5554)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'scmServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'scmdao'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'scmDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   javax/transaction/SystemException : Unsupported major.minor version
>   51.0 (unable to load class javax.transaction.SystemException)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
>     ... 32 more
>
> I have these jars in my lib

```
jboss-logging-3.1.1.GA.jar
activation-1.0.2.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar
aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b06.jar
apache-logging-log4j.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
javassist-3.4.GA.jar
javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
jta-1.1.jar
postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc3.jar
spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
```

My dispatcher-servlet.xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven /> 
<context:component-scan base-package="com.scm" />
<context:annotation-config />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" /> 

<bean id="jspViewResolver"

class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/SCM1" />
    <property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value="postgres123"/>
</bean> 


<bean id="sessionFactory" 
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />    
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.scm.Pojo.Req_Vcmd_Inter_Dist_Mas</value>
            <value>com.scm.Pojo.Req_Vcmd_Inter_Dist_Det</value>           
        </list>
    </property>     
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners"> 
false</prop> 
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql"> false   </prop> 

        </props>
    </property>
 </bean>

<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager" 
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" >
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

My srvice implementation class is

```
@Service
public class scmServiceImpl implements scmService {


@Autowired
private scmDao scmdao;

public scmDao getScmdao() {
    return scmdao;
}

public void setScmdao(scmDao scmdao) {
    this.scmdao = scmdao;
}

@Override
public List<Users> getUser(String username) {   
    return scmdao.getUser(username);
}
}
```

Controller is :

```
import com.scm.Beans.Users;
import com.scm.Service.scmService;


@Controller
public class myHomeController {

@Autowired
private scmService scm_service;

public scmService getScm_service() {
    return scm_service;
}

public void setScm_service(scmService scm_service) {
    this.scm_service = scm_service;
}


HttpSession session;

public HttpSession getSession() {
    return session;
}

public void setSession(HttpSession session) {
    this.session = session;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The message is quite clear:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/BasicLogger
```

You are missing the `jboss-logging.jar`. I suggest to use a dependency management system like Maven or Gradle to avoid such errors.

Comment: I have added  jboss-logging-3.1.1.GA.jar, but this time I am getting this exception  Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class javax.transaction.SystemException

Comment: Then your Java version is too old. Which version do you use?

Comment: @BharathPateru Please use same java version compiled jars to solve the Unsupported version error

Comment: @SangamBelose, I think jta-1.1.jar is my problem, I have searched for it and the results are saying  jta-1.1.jar is not compatible with java1.6, If yes, which jar should I use?

Comment: you are using jta 1.2 you should use jta 1.1 jar. Yes it is compatible not sure where you got that Idea that it wouldn't be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Access this link: https://start.spring.io  and create you basic application including all dependencies you must need.